# TinyMCE editor : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isMSIE' of null

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE (v3.5.8) and integrated iBrowser plugin (v1.4.5) with Codeigniter 2.1.3 and i'm getting the JavaScript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isMSIE' of null`
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

Error is in iBrowser plugin.

I didn't changed anything as from the downloaded file.

Error occurring in editor_plugin.js in iBrowser plugin folder.

iBrowser plugin url : http://seoroot.com/blog/computing/programming/tinymce-ibrowser-plugin.html

editor_plugin.js contains below code.

```
ib = null;

(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.IBrowserPlugin', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            // load common script
            tinymce.ScriptLoader.load(url + '/interface/common.js');

            // Register commands
            ed.addCommand('mceIBrowser', function() {
                var e = ed.selection.getNode();

                // Internal image object like a flash placeholder
                if (ed.dom.getAttrib(ed.selection.getNode(), 'class').indexOf('mceItem') != -1) {return}

                ib.isMSIE  = tinymce.isIE;
                ib.isGecko = tinymce.isGecko;
                ib.isWebKit= tinymce.isWebKit;
                ib.oEditor = ed; 
                ib.editor  = ed;
                ib.selectedElement = e;                 
                ib.baseURL = url + '/ibrowser.php'; 
                iBrowser_open();
            });

            // Register buttons
            ed.addButton('ibrowser', {
                title : 'iBrowser',
                cmd :   'mceIBrowser',
                image:  url + '/interface/images/tinyMCE/ibrowser.gif'
            });

            // Add a node change handler, selects the button in the UI when a image is selected
            ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
                cm.setActive('ibrowser', n.nodeName == 'IMG');
            });
        },

        getInfo : function() {
            return {
                longname :  'iBrowser',
                author :    'net4visions.com',
                authorurl : 'http://net4visions.com',
                infourl :   'http://net4visions.com/ibrowser.html',
                version :   '1.4.0'
            };
        }
    });

    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('ibrowser', tinymce.plugins.IBrowserPlugin);

})();
```

Sorry. Its a long code.

NOTE : **TinyMCE is working well but this plugin has some errors.**

Comment: Alright, just give me a few hours to set up a local instance exactly like that. Or, post the code where the error was thrown. Examine the call stack and see if it originated in your code. Then post your code.

Comment: I'll edit my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the first line of the code:

```
ib = null;
```

`null` cannot be accessed as an object. That will throw a `TypeError` as you've seen. The fix, I assume, would be to change this line to:

```
ib = {};
```

That way it is an object and can have its `isMSIE` property set.

However, I'm a little puzzled why this was explicitly set to `null`. I'd try changing that line of code and seeing if that breaks something, because there possibly could've been a reason for `ib` to initially be null.

Comment: i've set ib={} but i gets another error "Uncaught ReferenceError: iBrowser_open is not defined " - Line number 30. same js file.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha Indeed this function is undefined. Can you search the other source files for where it is defined? This plugin seems to be very buggy. Do you have the most recent version? You might want to write its author to let them know about the problem or file a bug report.

Comment: ys i've downloaded the file yesterday from their website. Thank you @phpMyCoder

Comment: I've edited path to include files and solved the error. also applied your fix. thank you.

Comment: add a tag iBrowser for TinyMCE if you have enough privilage. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the file editor_plugin.js (located in ibrowser root plugin folder) commented out the line:

```
tinymce.ScriptLoader.load(url + '/interface/common.js');
```

and add this

```
$.getScript(url+'/interface/common.js');
```

Do the same for editor_plugin_src.js as well.

Should be fixed.
The fix by @PhpMyCoder will work too. :)